# asp.net mvc decorate [Authorize()] with multiple enums

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization, roles

I have a controller and I want two roles to be able to access it. 1-admin OR 2-moderator

I know you can do [Authorize(Roles="admin, moderators")] but I have my roles in an enum. With the enum I can only authorize ONE role. I can't figure out how to authorize two.

I have tried something like [Authorize(Roles=MyEnum.Admin, MyEnum.Moderator)] but that wont compile.

Someone once suggested this:

```
 [Authorize(Roles=MyEnum.Admin)]
 [Authorize(MyEnum.Moderator)]
 public ActionResult myAction()
 {
 }
```

but it doesn't work as an OR. I think in this case the user has to be part of BOTH roles. Am I overlooking some syntax? Or is this a case where I have to roll my own custom authorization?

Comment: Interesting. How you were able to get this to work even with only one role in an enum?  Does MyEnum.Admin return a string?  I'm trying to do the same thing as you, and I've been running into a couple of problems:
- I can't set up a string type enum.
- I can't call ToString() on the enum e.g. [Authorize(Roles=MyEnum.Admin.ToString())] 

Both of the above examples gives me compiler errors.  If you can advise how you got this to work, that would be appreciated. Thx.

Comment: @JohnnyO - I have the same problem, did you manage to find out what we are doing wrong?  @codette - could you give us a tip here?

Comment: I'm sorry but I never went with any of these solutions. So I changed my code so that only one role needs to be checked. The higher their role is the more they can do. For example, a "normal" user can do a few things. A "moderator" can do all the things a "normal" user can and more. An "admin" can do everything a "normal" user and "moderator" can and more.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try using the bit OR operator like this:

```
[Authorize(Roles= MyEnum.Admin | MyEnum.Moderator)]
public ActionResult myAction()
{
}
```

If that doesn't work, you could just roll your own. I currently just did this on my project. Here's what I did:

```
public class AuthWhereRole : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Add the allowed roles to this property.
    /// </summary>
    public UserRole Is;

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks to see if the user is authenticated and has the
    /// correct role to access a particular view.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="httpContext"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("httpContext");

        // Make sure the user is authenticated.
        if (!httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            return false;

        UserRole role = someUser.Role; // Load the user's role here

        // Perform a bitwise operation to see if the user's role
        // is in the passed in role values.
        if (Is != 0 && ((Is & role) != role))
            return false;

        return true;
    }
}

// Example Use
[AuthWhereRole(Is=MyEnum.Admin|MyEnum.Newbie)]
public ActionResult Test() {}
```

Also, make sure to add a flags attribute to your enum and make sure they are all valued from 1 and up. Like this:

```
[Flags]
public enum Roles
{
    Admin = 1,
    Moderator = 1 << 1,
    Newbie = 1 << 2
    etc...
}
```

The left bit shifting gives the values 1, 2, 4, 8, 16 and so on.

Well, I hope this helps a little.

Comment: What if the user might belong to more than one role?

Comment: What value do I need to have in my database so that I select the Admin, Moderator or Newbie ? (db.users.role = 1 ; 2 ; 4 ; 8... ?

Comment: Using this solution you may have only 32 roles which may be ORed together. May be limiting (and for me it is). Better solution is the one from @ZaidMasud.

Answer (score 46):

Here is a **simple** and elegant solution which allows you to simply use the following syntax:

```
[AuthorizeRoles(MyEnum.Admin, MyEnum.Moderator)]
```

When creating your own attribute, use the ***`params`*** keyword in your constructor:

```
public class AuthorizeRoles : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public AuthorizeRoles(params MyEnum[] roles)
    {
        ...
    }
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

This will allow you to use the attribute as follows:

```
[AuthorizeRoles(MyEnum.Admin, MyEnum.Moderator)]
public ActionResult myAction()
{
}
```

Comment: I believe, this should be an accepted solution, as it works, and you are not limited to 32 roles at maximum in accepted answer. Thank you for this.

Comment: Just a hint on what's going on here (well - it fooled me for 5 mins!). You are creating the AuthorizeRoles object and then it will call the AuthorizeCore to find out if to give access or not. Something like this might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1148312/asp-net-mvc-decorate-authorize-with-multiple-enums

Comment: @zoka Agree. This solution is better and more flexible than mine. :)

Answer (score 16):

I combined a few of the solutions here to create my personal favorite. My custom attribute just changes the data to be in the form that SimpleMembership expects and lets it handle everything else.

My roles enum:

```
public enum MyRoles
{
    Admin,
    User,
}
```

To create roles:

```
public static void CreateDefaultRoles()
{
    foreach (var role in Enum.GetNames(typeof(MyRoles)))
    {
       if (!Roles.RoleExists(role))
       {
            Roles.CreateRole(role);
        }
    }
}
```

Custom attribute:

```
public class AuthorizeRolesAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public AuthorizeRolesAttribute(params MyRoles[] allowedRoles)
    {
        var allowedRolesAsStrings = allowedRoles.Select(x => Enum.GetName(typeof(MyRoles), x));
        Roles = string.Join(",", allowedRolesAsStrings);
    }
}
```

Used like so:

```
[AuthorizeRoles(MyRoles.Admin, MyRoles.User)]
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
public class CustomAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public enum Role
    {
        DomainName_My_Group_Name,
        DomainName_My_Other_Group_Name
    }

    public CustomAuthorize(params Role[] DomainRoles)
    {
        foreach (var domainRole in DomainRoles)
        {
            var domain = domainRole.ToString().Split('_')[0] + "_";
            var role = domainRole.ToString().Replace(domain, "").Replace("_", " ");
            domain=domain.Replace("_", "\\");
            Roles += ", " + domain + role;
        }
        Roles = Roles.Substring(2);
    }       
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [CustomAuthorize(Role.DomainName_My_Group_Name, Role.DomainName_My_Other_Group_Name)]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my version, based on @CalebHC and @Lee Harold's answers.

I've followed the style of using named parameters in the attribute and overridden the base classes `Roles` property.

@CalebHC's answer uses a new `Is` property which I think is unnecessary, because `AuthorizeCore()` is overridden (which in the base class uses Roles) so it makes sense to use our own `Roles` as well. By using our own `Roles` we get to write `Roles = Roles.Admin` on the controller, which follows the style of other .Net attributes.

I've used two constructors to `CustomAuthorizeAttribute` to show real active directory group names being passed in. In production I use the parameterised constructor to avoid magic strings in the class: group names are pulled from web.config during `Application_Start()` and passed in on creation using a DI tool.

You'll need a `NotAuthorized.cshtml` or similar in your `Views\Shared` folder or unauthorized users will get an error screen.

Here is the code for the base class [AuthorizationAttribute.cs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4828518/1239207).

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  return this.View();
}

[CustomAuthorize(Roles = Roles.Admin)]
public ActionResult About()
{
  return this.View();
}
```

CustomAuthorizeAttribute:

```
// The left bit shifting gives the values 1, 2, 4, 8, 16 and so on.
[Flags]
public enum Roles
{
  Admin = 1,
  User = 1 << 1    
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
  private readonly string adminGroupName;

  private readonly string userGroupName;

  public CustomAuthorizeAttribute() : this("Domain Admins", "Domain Users")
  {      
  }

  private CustomAuthorizeAttribute(string adminGroupName, string userGroupName)
  {
    this.adminGroupName = adminGroupName;
    this.userGroupName = userGroupName;
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Gets or sets the allowed roles.
  /// </summary>
  public new Roles Roles { get; set; }

  /// <summary>
  /// Checks to see if the user is authenticated and has the
  /// correct role to access a particular view.
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="httpContext">The HTTP context.</param>
  /// <returns>[True] if the user is authenticated and has the correct role</returns>
  /// <remarks>
  /// This method must be thread-safe since it is called by the thread-safe OnCacheAuthorization() method.
  /// </remarks>
  protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
  {
    if (httpContext == null)
    {
      throw new ArgumentNullException("httpContext");
    }

    if (!httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
      return false;
    }

    var usersRoles = this.GetUsersRoles(httpContext.User);

    return this.Roles == 0 || usersRoles.Any(role => (this.Roles & role) == role);
  }

  protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
  {
    if (filterContext == null)
    {
      throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
    }

    filterContext.Result = new ViewResult { ViewName = "NotAuthorized" };
  }

  private IEnumerable<Roles> GetUsersRoles(IPrincipal principal)
  {
    var roles = new List<Roles>();

    if (principal.IsInRole(this.adminGroupName))
    {
      roles.Add(Roles.Admin);
    }

    if (principal.IsInRole(this.userGroupName))
    {
      roles.Add(Roles.User);
    }

    return roles;
  }    
}
```

Comment: In case anyone actually tries to use this attribute with constructor injection, it won't work because attributes are created via the reflection API - see this [post](http://alexmg.com/post/2012/09/01/New-features-in-the-Autofac-MVC-4-and-Web-API-(Beta)-Integrations.aspx) for more info. The code posted above was a first cut before getting it working with DI.

Comment: In the end, I decided not to use DI with this because the lib I'm using (Autofac + Autofac.MVC4) only supports what I'm trying to achieve in a beta version, which I do not want to use. 

Here's a link about how to do this kind of thing with [Autofac.MVC4 beta](http://alexmg.com/post/2012/09/01/New-features-in-the-Autofac-MVC-4-and-Web-API-%28Beta%29-Integrations.aspx). 

My final version did away with the constructor arguments, and I converted `adminGroupName` and `userGroupName` into `const`.

Answer (score 1):

To decorate [Authorize()] with multiple enums, you can write code just like this:

```
[Authorize(Roles = nameof(MyEnum.Admin) + "," + nameof(MyEnum.Moderator))]
```

You are also can write this code for single role:

```
[Authorize(Roles = nameof(MyEnum.Admin))]
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to CalebHC's code and answer ssmith's question about handling users who have multiple roles...

Our custom security principal returns a string array representing all the groups/roles that a user is in. So first we have to convert all the strings in the array that match items in the enum. Finally, we look for any match - if so, then the user is authorized.

Note that we're also redirecting an unauthorized user to a custom "NotAuthorized" view.

The whole class looks like this:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)] 
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Add the allowed roles to this property.
    /// </summary>
    public Roles Is { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks to see if the user is authenticated and has the
    /// correct role to access a particular view.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="httpContext"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("httpContext");

        if (!httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            return false;

        var iCustomPrincipal = (ICustomPrincipal) httpContext.User;

        var roles = iCustomPrincipal.CustomIdentity
                        .GetGroups()
                        .Select(s => Enum.Parse(typeof (Roles), s))
                        .ToArray();

        if (Is != 0 && !roles.Cast<Roles>().Any(role => ((Is & role) == role)))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");

        filterContext.Result = new ViewResult { ViewName = "NotAuthorized" };
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not fully agree with the complexity of previous answers. Here's my version using a dictionary to convert Role enum values to string.

Of course, the mapping needs to be updated whenever there is a new role introduced.

```cs
public class AuthorizeRoles : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private Dictionary<Roles, string> _rolesMap = new()
    {
        // Fully qualified name since Roles already exist in AuthorizeAttribute
        { Common.Enums.Roles.User, "CustomRoles.User" },
        { Common.Enums.Roles.Manager, "CustomRoles.Manager" },
        { Common.Enums.Roles.Admin, "CustomRoles.Admin" },
    };
    
    public AuthorizeRoles(params Roles[] roles)
    {
        Roles = string.Join(",", roles.Select(role => _rolesMap[role]));
    }
}
```

Which can be used in the controllers like this

```cs
[AuthorizeRoles(Roles.User, Roles.Manager, Roles.Admin)]
```

Answer (score -1):

Or you could concatenate like:

```
[Authorize(Roles = Common.Lookup.Item.SecurityRole.Administrator + "," + Common.Lookup.Item.SecurityRole.Intake)]
```