# Access by roles at controller level

Tags: model-view-controller, controller, authorization

Is it possible with MVC to allow the whole controller to be accessed by 1 role **except** one or few methods be accessed by another role?

Where all methods belong to the staff except for Method3 can be access by both clients and staff. Something like below:

```
    [Authorize(Roles = "staff")]
    public class StaffController : Controller
    {
        public StaffController()
        {
        }
        public ActionResult Method1()
        {
        }
        public ActionResult Method2()
        {
        }
        [Authorize(Roles = "staff, customer")]
        public ActionResult Method3()
        {
        }
    }
```

Or another scenario where all belong to the staff except for Method3 where it is exclusively accessible by clients, like below:

```
    [Authorize(Roles = "staff")]
    public class StaffController : Controller
    {
        public StaffController()
        {
        }
        public ActionResult Method1()
        {
        }
        public ActionResult Method2()
        {
        }
        [Authorize(Roles = "customer")]
        public ActionResult Method3()
        {
        }
    }
```

However, the above don't work. In both cases, clients still don't have access to Method3.

Greatly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect it checks for controller authorisation first, so never gets a chance to check the specific actions for their authorisation.

One solution is to authorise both roles, at the class level, and restrict access on specific methods to just `staff`.

e.g.

```
[Authorize(Roles="staff,customer")]
public class StaffController : Controller
{
    [Authorize(Roles="staff")]
    public StaffController()
    {
    }
    [Authorize(Roles="staff")]
    public ActionResult Method1()
    {
    }
    [Authorize(Roles="staff")]
    public ActionResult Method2()
    {
    }
    public ActionResult Method3()
    {
    }
}
```

Another option is to `Restrict` (i.e. the opposite of `Authorize`) using something like the custom attribute on this answer [ASP.NET MVC: Opposite of [Authorise]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376595/asp-net-mvc-opposite-of-authorise)
but as they mention this goes against the "refuse by default" principal of MVC security.