# ASP.NET MVC Blacklist for Roles/Users

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, authorize-attribute, blacklist

**Question Summary:** In ASP.NET MVC, is there a clean way to prevent a specific user or role from accessing an action?

Obviously, the following would allow roles `Admin` and `Editor` to access the entire controller.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin, Editor")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

If I only wanted the `Admin` role to have access to the `About` action, I could do the following:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin, Editor")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")] // this will take precedence over the controller's authorization
    public ActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Is there a way to accomplish this without listing every single role that *needs* access, and only specifying the roles that should be *prevented* from having access?

Comment: so, a Blacklist instead of a Whitelist

Comment: @Jonesy - Yes, essentially.

Comment: you could write your own `[BlackListAttribute]`, that accepts roles in the same fashion

Comment: agree with Jonesy you could extend a new class from AuthorizeAttribute and build your own

Comment: [You mean something like this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376595/asp-net-mvc-opposite-of-authorise)

Comment: yeah exactly you need to do some logic to fetch only blacklist people you don't want to access that controller or specific function

Comment: Check out this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376595/asp-net-mvc-opposite-of-authorise

Comment: We consider what .Net calls a "role" a permission, we grant permission to Users, so rather than saying [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")] we use [Authorize(Roles = "Home.About")]. Now what we call "Roles" is a set of permissions. User's are put in our "roles".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code for the class I used to solve this problem. It derives heavily from `AuthorizeAttribute`, and will allow any authenticated user through who does **not** match the specifications set by the parameters.

(Note that the important method is `AuthorizeCore` - everything else is essentially copied or inherited from `AuthorizeAttribute`)

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class BlackListAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private static readonly string[] _emptyArray = new string[0];

    private string _roles;
    private string _users;

    private string[] _rolesSplit = _emptyArray;
    private string[] _usersSplit = _emptyArray;

    public new string Roles
    {
        get { return _roles ?? String.Empty; }
        set
        {
            _roles = value;
            _rolesSplit = SplitString(value);
        }
    }

    public new string Users
    {
        get { return _users ?? String.Empty; }
        set
        {
            _users = value;
            _usersSplit = SplitString(value);
        }
    }
    // This is the important part. Everything else is either inherited from AuthorizeAttribute or, in the case of private or internal members, copied from AuthorizeAttribute.
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(System.Web.HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("httpContext");
        }

        IPrincipal user = httpContext.User;

        if (user == null || user.Identity == null || !user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (_usersSplit.Length > 0 && _usersSplit.Contains(user.Identity.Name, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (_rolesSplit.Length > 0 && _rolesSplit.Any(user.IsInRole))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    internal static string[] SplitString(string original)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(original))
        {
            return _emptyArray;
        }

        var split = from piece in original.Split(',')
                    let trimmed = piece.Trim()
                    where !String.IsNullOrEmpty(trimmed)
                    select trimmed;
        return split.ToArray();
    }
}
```

You can use it on controllers or actions like any other `AuthorizeAttribute`:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin, Editor")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [BlackList(Roles = "Editor")]
    public ActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create your own blacklist class just like this one:

```
public class Blacklist : AuthorizeAttribute {
    private List<string> RolesList;
    public string Roles {
        get {
            string roles = "";
            if (RolesList!= null && RolesList.Count > 0) {
                int counter = 0;
                foreach (string role in RolesList) {
                    counter++;
                    if (counter == RolesList.Count)
                        roles = role;
                    else 
                        roles += role + ",";
                }
            }
            return roles;
        }
        set {
            RolesList = new List<string>();
            string[] roles = value.Split(',');
            foreach (string role in roles) {
                RolesList.Add(role);
            }
        }
    }
//constructor 
    public Blacklist () {
        RolesList = new List<string>();
    }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext) {
        bool result = true;
        if (httpContext == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("httpContext");
        }
        foreach (string role in RolesList) {
            if (httpContext.User.IsInRole(role)) {
                result = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Now you are going to block the roles you want:

```
[Authorize]
[Blacklist (Roles = "Admin", "Editor")]
    public ActionResult Index() {
    return View();
}
```

Comment: yeah, maybe you could create your own answer and post it instead of commenting something that is not constructive at all.