# Dynamic access to actionresults

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, privileges, roleprovider, custom-membershipprovider

Allow users with roles to access controller methods dynamically.
I have a typical scenario where I want to allow users to access the pages dynamically as the prvilege set to each roles can be change by a userinterface.
I have three actionresult

Controller:

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
 {
[CustomAuthorize(Roles="Admin")]
Public Actionresult UI01(){
return View();
}

[CustomAuthorize(Roles="Admin")]
Public Actionresult UI02(){
return View();
}

[CustomAuthorize(Roles="Admin")]
Public Actionresult UI03(){
return View();
}
}
```

View:
I hide the menu items by checking the admin role.

```
@*menu items*@
  @if((Roles.IsUserInRole("Admin")){
  <li>@Html.ActionLink("Rating", "UI01", "Home")</li>
}
@if((Roles.IsUserInRole("Admin")){

  <li>@Html.ActionLink("Map", "UI02", "Home")</li>
}
@if((Roles.IsUserInRole("Admin")){
  <li>@Html.ActionLink("Sales", "UI03", "Home")</li>
}
```

authorize attribute classs:

```
public class CustomAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
            }
            else
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new
                RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Account", action = "Error" }));
            }
        }
    }
```

I have a seperate module to assign privilege to the users to access the UI01,UI02,UI03 as following.

```
    Page name   Admin   Employee  Customer
------------------------------------------------
    Rating      1         0         0
    Map         1         0         0
    Sales       1         0         0

    *1-allow
    *0-Deny access
```

Currenly All the three UIs allow only Admin role. But I need to set access dynamically to the Controller methods with respective of the privilege set in the above UI.

**Edit:**
I have created Customauthorize attribute for each Page/actionresult and got the result successfully using the method in this link
[asp.net mvc decorate [Authorize()] with multiple enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1148312/asp-net-mvc-decorate-authorize-with-multiple-enums)

But my problem now is to hide the menus in layout(view) page

Answer (score 1):

At the moment your assigning privileges to "groups" of users. It might be easier to assign the privileges to the individual users using something more like:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [CustomAuthorize(Roles="Rating")]
    public ActionResult UI01(){
        return View();
    }

    [CustomAuthorize(Roles="Map")]
    public ActionResult UI02(){
        return View();
    }

    [CustomAuthorize(Roles="Sales")]
    public ActionResult UI03(){
        return View();
    }
}
```

And the UI would look like:

```
@*menu items*@
@if((Roles.IsUserInRole("Rating")){
  <li>@Html.ActionLink("Rating", "UI01", "Home")</li>
}

@if((Roles.IsUserInRole("Map")){
  <li>@Html.ActionLink("Map", "UI02", "Home")</li>
}

@if((Roles.IsUserInRole("Sales")){
  <li>@Html.ActionLink("Sales", "UI03", "Home")</li>
}
```

You could then create an admin page to assign the roles to users. Using code like:

```
System.Web.Security.Roles.AddUserToRole("MyUserName", "Rating");
```

Comment: Thankyou for your time , I dont't get it.Can you please brief it how can i get values to Roles("Rating") dynamically?

Comment: You can create an admin page and use: `Roles.AddUserToRole("MyUserName", "Rating");`

Comment: I have predefined roles called as'Admin','Employee' and 'customer'.Currently users having Admin privilege can access all the UIs since '1' is set . admin access can be restricted if I change SAles to '0' .

Comment: I was suggesting you could add new Roles (Rating, Map & Sales) and assign these to individual users but maybe this doesn't suit your needs. If you want to assign Privileges to Roles (e.g. Rating to Employee then you'll have to write a fair bit of custom code).

Comment: I suppose you could have an admin page that loops over all users in a particular role (e.g. Employee) and adds the privileges (e.g. Rating - just another role) to each user.

Comment: According to my  functionality, I cannot decide whther to add a user to a particular group role since the privilege for a role is dynamic.  :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57149/discussion-between-gs11111-and-lee-gunn).