# Authorize with custom enums in model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller that I want to set custom settings for people to be able to see it.

Controller

```
    [Authorize(UserRoles.Admin)]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
        //SqlConnect(url);

    }
```

Model

```
public enum UserRoles
{
    Admin,
    Employee,
    Guest
}
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User Role")]
    public UserRoles UserRoles { get; set; }
}
```

I keep seeing syntax that say that this is the correct way to do it, but I can't get it to work. Help please and thank you.

Comment: similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1148312/asp-net-mvc-decorate-authorize-with-multiple-enums

Comment: I'm confused as to where the custom attribute goes. The only leads I get are to metadata.

Comment: In the first sample code, if you want to restrict access to that method in your controller to only 'Admin'. Then, you can use this [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")] That data annotation will allow only users with a registered role in the Admin role. If you want to allow other roles add them inside the quotes separated with a comma.

Comment: You might want to show your razor code to show how you're using the enum. That way others here can have a better idea of what you're trying to do and help you find a solution.

Answer (score -2):

This is incorrect syntax:

```
public UserRoles UserRoles { get; set; }
```

You can't name a variable the same name as the class, try instead:

```
public UserRoles _userRoles { get; set; }
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: It did not. I do need to work on naming conventions better, but as for now, I'm trying to get it to run. Thanks though.

Comment: The error that it gives me is 'AuthorizeAttribute' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments'

Comment: Ah. Sorry, im not sure then.

Comment: Of course you can name the variable the same as the class (and it common to do so)